# Why does ptrace not recognize the function?

Tags: c, ptrace

I can't figure out why the function returns an "No such process" error message every time I run it, but simply using the same instructions inline produces the required output.

```
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/user.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void getregs(pid_t proc, struct user_regs_struct *regs);

int main() {
        pid_t proc = fork();

        if(proc == 0) {
                if(ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, NULL, NULL) == -1) {
                       perror("traceme");
                       exit(0);
                }

                if(execl("child", "child", NULL) == -1) {
                       perror("execl");
                       exit(0);
                }
        } else {
                wait(&proc);
                struct user_regs_struct regs;
                ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, proc, NULL, &regs);
                printf("eax: %08x\n", (unsigned int)regs.eax);
                getregs(proc, &regs);
                ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, proc, NULL, NULL);
        }

        return 0;
}

void getregs(pid_t proc, struct user_regs_struct *regs) {
        if(ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, proc, NULL, &regs) == -1) {
                perror("GETREGS");
                exit(1);
        }

        printf("eax: %08x\n", (unsigned int)regs->eax);
}
```

When I run this I get

```
~$ ./tracer 
eax: 0000002f 
GETREGS: No such process
```

I don't get why `getregs()` returns that error. It's almost like it is outside scope of something?

*Also, something a little unrelated: EAX is always set to `0000002f` no matter what process I try to `execl()`. Is this natural? I don't know if i'm forking the child process properly or not. Would I need to make a new question on SO for this?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You hit this error because you are modifying the value of the process identifier (PID) contained in the variable `proc` by passing its address to the [`wait(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html) syscall.

The `wait` syscall will change the value of `proc` with the return status of your child process upon its termination. So when you reference your child process in `ptrace`  using `proc`, its value will likely be invalid and referencing no existing processes.

And as *@lornix* noticed, make sure that you pass the right pointer to `ptrace` in the `getregs` function.

Comment: I've updated the code. Also I tried removing `wait(2)` entirely, but nothing changes.

Comment: Keep waiting, but instead of passing `proc` to it, pass the address of another integer.

Comment: +1 for seeing the issue right away, I had to work my way through it.

Comment: @HalimQarroum Well, now the value of EAX is `00000000`, but the function `getregs` still fails.

Comment: What did change in your code ? Could you create a page on http://codepad.org/ with your updated code so we can see what changed ?

Comment: seg fault in getregs?   remove the __&__.  Worked for me.

Comment: @HalimQarroum http://codepad.org/O8ErYB8A this is what the code looks like right now. I even have `&` removed like @lornix said, but it still doesn't change anything. :(

Comment: @user3407764 That's because you are passing 0 to `ptrace` in the getregs function instead of passing the proc variable.

Comment: Code looks good on codepad, don't see what problem might be, unless issue with execl("child"... call.    As an aside, you should check return values of functions with `!=0` rather than `== -1`, since there are many possible bad return values, but only one good return value (== 0). Arg! Congrats @HalimQarroum, missed that 0 in getregs ptrace call.

Comment: @HalimQarroum wtf, when did I change that? Jesus christ, the function works now. Thank you very much. One final question? Should I be using `waitpid` instead of `wait` or does it even matter?

Comment: Your usage of `waitpid` is functionally identical to `wait`.  Doesn't matter which one you use.  `wait` is easier overall.

Comment: The way you call `waitpid` (i.e `waitpid(-1, &status, 0)`) in your function is equivalent to using `wait` with one argument.

Comment: Ya, @HalimQarroum earned this one, plus all the comments here better document things.

Answer (score 2):

```
void getregs(pid_t proc, struct user_regs_struct *regs) {
        if(ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, proc, NULL, &regs) == -1) {
```

You need to dereference regs in the ptrace call. (remove **&** in this case)

```
        if(ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, proc, NULL, regs) == -1) {
```

you're calling getregs with the ADDRESS of regs, so getregs' regs is not a structure like in the main code, it's a pointer to a structure.

---

EDIT: figured it out

You're using/reassigning **proc** in the wait call, shouldn't do that.  The parameter to wait is a status value, not the pid of a particular child.  Wait *waits* for *any* child, see *waitpid* for a pid specific wait.

Try:

```
int wait_status;
wait(&wait_status);
```

in place of the current wait function call.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't fix it. It's still the same errors.

Comment: whoops!  Overlooked the obvious... do you HAVE a program named 'child' that is being executed in the 'execl' function?    You're not checking return status of ptrace function in main, but are checking it in getregs.  modifying main to check return status returns same 'no such process'.   There's nothing being run, since 'child' doesn't exist to run.  (also, execl does not use PATH to find program, so full path must be supplied, use execlp to have it use PATH to find executable)

Comment: Yes, in a revisioned version I am checking the return value of both execl and the ptrace_traceme, and they do not display any errors.

Answer (score 1):

Both your `ptrace` calls are behaving the same way. The difference is that you're ignoring the return value of the inline one, whereas the one in the function is checked.

The `EAX` value is a red herring: the structure is not initialized because the `PTRACE_GETREGS` failed.

The `wait` function does not take a process ID. It waits for some process to terminate and puts its status into the integer value that is passed in by pointer.

You want `waitpid` (if you want to wait for a specific child process). The simple function `wait` is useful when you know there is only one:

```
int status;
if (wait(&status)) { ... }
```

Comment: I added an if statement around the inline ptrace call, and checked if it returned -1, but it didn't. Additionally, I changed wait to `waitpid(-1, &status, 0);` where status is some integer variable. Much like the above with Halim Qarroum, it changed EAX to `00000000` but didn't fix the `getregs` problem.